# Convert string date column to int column for merge in python

Tags: pandas, datetime, databricks

I have two dataframe and I have to merge them with a date column,
The column of the first dataframe is an integer(year,month and day) and the second is a str(%d,/%m/&Y)
How can I convert the str dataframe to join them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What we do is convert both of them to date format.

```
df1.Date=pd.to_datetime(df1.Date,format='%Y%m%d')
df2.Date=pd.to_datetime(df2.Date,format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Then `join` or `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2, on = 'Date')# df1.join(df2) when the Date is index
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I get this:ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Comment: @Jozamvg have you figure it out or understand what is that error message means?